# why does outlier.colour work in geom_boxplot() but not in layer( ..., geom_params(...) )

Tags: r, ggplot2

I expected these to give the same results, but they did not:

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=color))
p + layer( geom="boxplot", geom_params=list(colour="navy", fill="skyblue"),
           stat="boxplot", stat_params=list(coef=2))
p + geom_boxplot(colour='navy',fill="skyblue")
```

It appears that in the first, `colour` is used for both the boxes and the outliers, but only for the boxes in the second.  What am I misunderstanding?